# PHP preg_match_all same line

Tags: php, regex

Having trouble with a regular expression (they are not my strong suit).  I'm trying to match all strings between {{ and }}, but if a set of brackets occurs on the same line, it counts that as a single match... Example:

```
$string = "
  Hello, kind sir
  {{SHOULD_MATCH1}} {{SHOULD_MATCH2}}
  welcome to
  {{SHOULD_MATCH3}}
  ";

preg_match_all("/{{(.*)}}/", $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches); // returns arrays with 2 results instead of 3
```

returns:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(35) "{{SHOULD_MATCH1}} {{SHOULD_MATCH2}}"
    [1]=>
    string(17) "{{SHOULD_MATCH3}}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(31) "SHOULD_MATCH1}} {{SHOULD_MATCH2"
    [1]=>
    string(13) "SHOULD_MATCH3"
  }
}
```

Any help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the `*` quantifier with its [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) form `*?`.

This will make it match as little as possible while still allowing the expression to match as a whole, which is different from its current behavior of matching as much as possible.

Comment: Or you can add the flag "U" to force non-greedy mode. Like `preg_match_all("/{{(.*)}}/U", $string, $matches)`

Comment: Accepted for explanation, thanks Jon.  +1 to Fab Sa for a correct answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one the following patterns.

1. `{{(.+?)}`
2. `{{([^}]+)`
3. `{{(\w+)`
4. `{{([[:digit:][:upper:]_]+)`
5. `{{([\p{Lu}\p{N}_]+)`